# Unit test also methods in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, mockito-kotlin

I have a test function for the `duplicate` method of my service, and this method ends with a `.also` call, that runs after the return of the method. But my test isn't covering this.

I have the following code with a `.also` call at the end

```kotlin
    suspend fun duplicate(id: ObjectId): Foo {
        val foo = findById(id)
        reset(foo)
        return create(foo).also {
           externalClient.doSomething(foo)
        }
    }
```

And this is the test for this function

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `should duplicate`() = runTest {
        wheneverBlocking { fooRepository.findById(any()) } doReturn Foo().apply {
            ...
        }
        wheneverBlocking { fooRepository.save(any()) } doAnswer { it.getArgument(0) }

        val res = fooService.duplicate(ObjectId())

        verify(externalclient, times(1)).doSomething(any())
    }
```

When I run the test, the verify doesn't pass, what can I do so it unit test the `.also` method?

Comment: I think the design needs rethinking. Are you sure you need using `also` here? Why can't you call the `externalClient` like this: `externalClient.doSomething(duplicate(id))`?

Comment: I also would like to see the implementation of `create(foo: Foo)` method

Comment: @Steyrix The method `create(foo: Foo)` itś just for saving it in the repository and returns the same object with the id.
And I can't call it directly because I don't want to wait the return of the externalClient method